# Notification system on nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

For example I have a user. User have e birthday 10.10.2010. How to make notification when we will have date 10.10.2020 and for example send email or make some changes in db.

I think that it can be something like timer maybe or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this module: https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule

```js
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
const date = new Date(2020, 10, 10, 5, 30, 0); // trigger at 2020/10/10 5:30 am

const j = schedule.scheduleJob(date, () => {
  // do something here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a service or some other type of scheduled job that fires at intervals. Maybe a Cron job if your hosting platform provides it.

When the job runs, it calls your NodeJS endpoint, which does a search for birthday records with the current date whose Processed flag have not been set to true. Then you compose and send your mails, and then set all the records' Processed flag to True before updating them in the database. This way you won't process the same ones more than once.

Ideally you'd want to put all the mails in a queue, rather than sending them straight from the endpoint.